# How to use distributed training with a custom loss using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing

I have a transformer model I'd like to train distributed across several workers on the Google Cloud AI Platform using Actor-Critic RL for training. I have my data broken up into individual files by date and uploaded to Cloud Storage. Since I'm using Actor-Critic RL, I have a custom loss function that calculates and applies the gradient. All the examples I've come across for distributed training make use of `model.fit`, which I'm not going to be able to do. I haven't been able to find any information on using a custom loss instead.

Along with distributing it across several machines, I'd like to know how to properly distribute training across several CPU cores as well. From my understanding `model.fit` takes care of this stuff normally.

Here's the custom loss function; right now it's the equivalent of a batch size of 1 I believe:

```
def learn(self, state_value_starting: tf.Tensor, probabilities: tf.Tensor, state_new: tf.Tensor,
            reward: tf.Tensor, is_done: tf.Tensor):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        state_value_starting = tf.squeeze(state_value_starting)
        state_value_new, _ = self.call(state_new)
        state_value_new = tf.squeeze(state_value_new)

        action_probabilities = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=probabilities)
        log_probability = action_probabilities.log_prob(self._last_action)

        delta = reward + (self._discount_factor * state_value_new * (1 - int(is_done))) - state_value_starting
        actor_loss = -log_probability * delta
        critic_loss = delta ** 2
        total_loss = actor_loss + critic_loss

    gradient = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient, self.trainable_variables))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tensorflow Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) is provided with a practiced solution, defined in [model_lib_v2.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py).

See the function `train_loop`, the custom training loop is constructed makes use of

```
strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.get_strategy() #L501
with strategy.scope():
    training step ...
```

And custom loss in function `eager_train_step`.